# What is the range of learning rate which makes gradient descent converge and not converge for this loss?

Tags: gradient-descent

[image: https://latex.codecogs.com/gif.latex?L%28w1%2Cw2%29%20%3D%20.5%28xw_%7B1%7D%5E%7B2%7D%20+%20yw_%7B2%7D%5E%7B2%7D%29]

Range in terms of x and y
As you might be aware that gradient descent uses

alpha  = learning rate

W* = W -alpha*(dL/dW)

x,y are constant